# C# Repository Pattern? Complex queries still placed inside repository?

Tags: c#, database, repository-pattern

I am learning the Repository Pattern. I have managed to write the code to do it.

I read the article say each Repository related to one entities.

This is what i have for my Repository:

```
public class ProductRepository : BaseProductRepository
{ 
    public ProductRepository(StoreDBContext context) : base(context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public override async Task<IEnumerable<TResult>> GetTopProducts<TResult>(Func<Product, TResult> selectFunc)
    {
        var products = this.context.Product
            .Select(selectFunc)
            .ToList();
        
        return products;
    }
     
}
```

I am having the generic and expression in the method is because I want to have the caller to define what result should be e.g. partial data from product instead of all the data of a product.

Now i encounter an issue. What if the query is little complex which e.g. more table to join and the resulting data is returning not only the data of the Product, may be the number of users purchased the product etc.

Where can those complex query's which return complex dataset would be?

Comment: There is a school of thought that says when using entity framework, the DB context is already your repository for this pattern.  I've seen a lot of people try and wrap around the context for separation and wind up just implementing a slightly worse version of Linq.

Comment: I think, you'll need to grab a book or two. This is really out of scope for SO, IMHO.

Comment: You can also read up on [CQRS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/cqrs) pattern

Answer (score 0):

TResult should be in the 'shape' that the method relates to.  It certainly shouldn't be a database entity.

In your case TResult for GetTopProducts would be a collection of product summaries.

```
class GetTopProductsResult
{
    public IEnumerable<Product> TopProducts {get;set;}
    public class Product
    {
       public int Id {get;set;}
       public string Name {get;set;}
       public int UnitsSold {get;set;}
    }
}
```

I also suggest you look at [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/) which will basically implement your `Select` function in a more structured way.